# Redis wipes out the data in it

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

Is there any reason why Redis is flusing all the data in it every day?
I've installed the official docker image for Redis in one of my machines, put some data in it, but the day after it's all gone.
The data is being saved through Spring Data Redis, so it's all sets and objects, but I checked the `TTL` for each one of them is -1.

```
local:0>ttl com.example.entity.MyObject
-1
```

I'm forcing the dump to disk after saving this object, and I double checked the data is still there after restarting the container, but still, I dunno why, it's gone after a while.

Comment: Have you checked for eviction (i.e. memory gets consumed and then Redis free's its memory by evicting keys)?

Comment: Have you checked that your server isn't open to the public? It could be someone unauthorized connecting to your server and flushing it.

Comment: @mp911de I'm forcing saving into disk using bgSave(), so even if it evicts it from memory it should be still in the file, right?